# Using different left and right quote characters with openCSV in Java

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to read a CSV file in Java using [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). However the csv file uses `<` and `>` as quote characters instead of `"`.

According to [this](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#custom-sepators) there is a way to change the quote character used, but is it possible to change to `<` and `>`? If so, how?

Comment: I would assume that it want's to use the same open and close character

Comment: I assume so too, any recommendations on a Java CSV reader that can do what I want? I would prefer to not write my own.

Comment: I might be tempted to pre-process the data and replace the "<" and ">" characters with my open quote character...

Comment: Seems like the few libraries I've looked over all expect a single quote character...